# RedirectToAction, areas and passing class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a site in .Net Core (Netcoreapp 1.1).  At one point, I need to redirect an action from one controller to another and pass information to the destination action using the following code:

```
public class MyInfo() 
{
    public string Area {get;set;}
    public string Controller {get;set;}
    public string Action {get;set;}
    public string UserId {get;set;}
}

public class FirstController() : Controller 
{
    public IActionResult SelectUser() 
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SelectUser", "Users", new 
        {
            Area = "Security",
            model = new MyInfo()  
            {
                Area = "Weapons",
                Controller = "First",
                Action = "SelectUserCallback",
            }
        });
    }
}

public class UsersController() : Controller 
{
    public IActionResult SelectUser(MyInfo model)  
    {
        //Show a dialog, set the results in model and return
    }
}
```

The object of this code is to display a dialog showing a list of users, allow selecting one user and then return the selected user to a callback represented by MyInfo.  The `SelectUser` function is called correctly and the model is not null, but all of the properties of the model are null.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Passing parameters from one action to another action is not supported in .net mvc as of yet. You will need to use a temporary storage solution like temp data or session or persistent storage like a database for this to work the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution.  It seems that parameters can be passed from one action to another, just not as a complex object.  I changed the signature of my method to:

```
public IActionResult SelectUser(string callbackAction, string callbackController, string callbackArea)
```

And all the information is passed correctly.